# Android Menu Item Title not displaying

Tags: android, menu, title

I've been fiddling with android, and I've been following the menu sample, and it runs almost fine, but the "title" field of the menu items isn't displaying.

I think it's related to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286093/android-menu-item-not-showing-text
but I'm not sure what his answer means.

Anyway, it properly gets that I have 2 menu items, it just isn't displaying the text. I'm not quite sure where the error is and figured extra sets of eyes would be good.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:id="@+id/options"
  android:title="@string/main_options" />
 <item android:id="@+id/options2"
  android:title="@string/main_options2" />
</menu>
```

Inflator:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

If anything else is needed, let me know.

edit:
string file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World!</string>
    <string name="app_name">LifeInColor</string>
 <string name="main_options">Options</string>
 <string name="main_options2">Something goes here</string>
</resources>
```

changing the xml to:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@+id/options"
      android:title="@string/main_options" />
     <item android:id="@+id/options2"
      android:title="Something goes here" />
    </menu>
```

gets the same result. I have a picture, but it won't let me post it because I'm new.

Comment: Can you show your strings file?  Did you try using explicit string values? (Not that thats recommended, but just as a test..)

Comment: code edited into the first post.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong :/  I assume you read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html  You can try putting a break point after inflate to see what the menu object looks like..

Comment: That's what I've been following. It's pretty much mostly copy and pasted from that.

I added a breakpoint and stepped through it after the inflate (@ the return), and looking into "menu" and then "mItems" (which I assume is the menu items), both menu items have their "mTitle" set to "null"

Comment: You double checked that you are loading the correct menu file?  What if you add an icon to the menu items?

Comment: adding icons does not display any icons either, but adding other <item> tags by copy and pasting others results in the correct amount of items showing up there. They just all happen to be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your menu file replace `https://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` with `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android` (**https** -> **http**). So it looks like the error was due to incorrect schema address.

Comment: You shouldn't the problem wasn't that obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the icon is too large. If you use an icon of more than 48x48 on an hdpi screen, the user will either see no title or see a truncated title.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html#size9

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify an icon with `android:icon="@null"`to each item, then the title was shown. This works if using Toolbar.

Comment: It might be odd, but this also worked for me. Leaving out the icon tag showed nothing at all, setting a specific icon left out the text. Setting it to @null shows the text.

Answer (score 0):

Directly we can add menu items like this , it working fine for me

```
       @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
           {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
             MenuItem item1=menu.add(0, 4, 0,"text1");
            item1.setIcon(R.drawable.car);
            MenuItem item2=menu.add(0, 0, 0, "text2");
             item2.setIcon(R.drawable.share);
            MenuItem item3=menu.add(0, 2, 0, "text3");
           item3.setIcon(R.drawable.history);
           MenuItem item4=menu.add(0, 3, 0, "text4");
           item4.setIcon(R.drawable.settings);
    return true;
}
```