# Menu item Title is not displayed if Menu icon is added with a action layout

Tags: android, menuitem

I have added following menu item in menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_reveal_item"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_for_menu_icon"
    android:visible="false">
```

Adding menu item title, Icon image into the action layout programmatically, Where everything works fine. Except menu item title is not displayed.

How to change the code? Or we need to write on item long click listeners to rectify this?

P.s : Have tried the following solutions But not working. [Android Menu Item Title not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764061/android-menu-item-title-not-displaying)

[Menu icon is not displaying in action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562565/menu-icon-is-not-displaying-in-action-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the item tag

```
android:title="yourTitle"
```

Something like

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_reveal_item"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_for_menu_icon"
    android:title="yourTitle"
    android:visible="false">
```

Comment: I am setting title programmatically. I had tried with title in xml too.(Edited the question now) It is not working